# Adding Physical Parallel Port to ESXi 5.1 host

Tags: vmware-esxi

I recently installed a PCIe parallel port into one of our ESXi hosts so I could migrate an old PC onto it that requires a parallel port dongle. I'm having a problem though, because I cannot add the port to a VM because the option I need is grayed out.

[image]

My processor does not have support for VT-d, so that option is out also. Is there no way to make use of PCI devices that are installed on the host? My NICs seem to work fine so I figured adding a parallel port shouldn't be much different.

Is there any way to get this thing working?

*ESXi: 5.1

Processor: Intel E7420

Server: Dell R900

RAM: 128GB*

Comment: Don't you need to configure PCI passthrough on the host, then pass the card directly to the VM?

Comment: @joeqwerty I believe that requires VT-d

Answer (score 2):

You're out of luck. Either downgrade to ESXi 4.1 (5.x does not support physical ports) or upgrade to a VT-d system. Or maybe find some weird paralell-over-IP system.. if you dare..

Source: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2218034